# how to update google sheet from google doc without showing google sheet in shared with me to user

Tags: google-apps-script

is there a way to update google sheet from google doc where google sheet will not show to user in shared with me list.

Currently user is using add-on from google doc to update google sheet which is shared with all user. If we don't share appscript will not be able to update google sheet.

Problem is user able to see the master google sheet data under Shared with me list in google drive.

Comment: Hello! So you have a google doc, which the user is on, and user has an add-on which updates a master sheet, and you don't want the sheet to be visible, correct?

Comment: yes absolutely.

Comment: also would like to know how others are processsing user data is it always a backend database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, an Add-on is an Apps Script and a Script [does actions *on behalf* of the user](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-scopes), if the user's Script can *edit* a Sheet, then they *must* have access to that sheet. It makes sense for security purposes.

Workaround:
In all cases, the owner of the Spreadsheet *must* be the *only* one who *can* run the Script.

- You could rewrite the Add-on to live within the master sheet.
- You could run a simple script from the master sheet to fetch data from the docs. Maybe on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).
- You could [set up a web-app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), and then the Docs add-on could make a POST request to the web-app.
- You could set up a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) that will send data to a Google Spreadsheet which the users won't have access to.